# grep specific filetypes on MAC

Tags: macos, grep

I have a Mac OS X snow leopard. I am using the xterm terminal to grep specific string using this command `grep -R --color=auto setHeader *.js` but when I run this command I get the error saying

```
grep: \*.js: No such file or directory
```

So my question is how can I grep for a specific filetype on Mac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do that is to combine the `find` and the `grep` command:

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec grep --color=auto setHeader {} \;
```

Answer (score 8):

`grep --include=*.js -R . --color=auto setHeader`

Since the example given uses "file type = file extension", this should just work.

Answer (score 6):

This one works for me on Mac OS 10.8:

```
grep --include=*.js -r setHeader .
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "-R" flag.  When using that, you need to specify a directory.  You'd be better off using a find command:

find . -name "*.js" -exec grep "setHeader" '{}' \;

If you want to use grep, just use "." instead of "*.js" for the file pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that there are no '*.js' files in your current directory. If you want to traverse a directory tree, then you could do this:

```
find <startdirectory> -name '*.js' -exec grep --color=auto setHeader '{}' ';'
```

Of course you need to fill in the correct *startdirectory*, you can use `.` to denote the directory you're currently in.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
mdfind -name .extn | grep .extn$
```

Where extn is the file type you are searching for (in my case .tre) and of course `$` is end of line. The grep doesnt work inside quotes `''`