# grep/ack on Mac OS X finding multiple strings and respecting file types

Tags: regex, macos, bash, grep, ack

I would like to run `grep` on Mac OS X that would meeting the following criteria:

- search all files with `*.R` or `*.r` as extension and ignore other files
- Find strings: `wordA` and `wordB` accounting for the fact that the strings may appear in the format **`someRubbishWordARubbish`** (this is a valid match)
- List only the files where **both** strings appear *irrespectively of the order*
- Print the lines where the strings appear
- Highlight the found words in colour
- Print the file name as a header and lines under the header. I'm inspired by the [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/) options.
- Ignoring the case

## Approach

I was thinking of making use of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380032/grep-specific-filetypes-on-mac) and starting with the following `grep` syntax:

```
grep --include=*.R -r setHeader .
```

Then combining it with the following:

```
grep 'word1\|word2\|word3' /path
```

However, I would appreciate comments on ensuring that all of the criteria stated above will be evaluated correctly.

### Groups

```
^(.*)(facet|map)(.*)(map|facet)(.*)$
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dV8lM1/1)

---

### Ack

Running `ack -f` shows that `*.R` files would be searched so solutions using `ack` will be accepted. For example, running:

```
ack wordA --colour -i -H --rr
```

gets the desired results with respect to the **wordA**. I was thinking of combining it the solutions discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275582/searching-multiple-patterns-words-with-ack) but I would like to use **AND** not **OR** and ignore the order in which strings may appear. I further tried:

```
ack --match wordA --match wordB  --colour -i -H --rr
```

But this produced only the results for `wordB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that combines the closely-named `awk` and `ack` commands:

```sh
find . -iname '*.r' | while read file; do
    awk '
        BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1; sawWordA = 0; sawWordB = 0 }
        /wordA/ { sawWordA = 1 }
        /wordB/ { sawWordB = 1 }
        sawWordA && sawWordB { exit } # stop reading lines if both matches seen
        END { exit !(sawWordA && sawWordB) }
        ' \
        "${file}" \
    && ack --nofilter -H -i 'wordA|wordB' "${file}"
done
```

The awk command...

- Lists only the files where both strings appear irrespectively of the order
- Ignores the case

...and the ack command...

- Prints the lines where the strings appear
- Highlights the found words in colour
- Prints the file name as a header and lines under the header inspired by the ack options
- Ignores the case

The awk script sets flags if there are search string matches. If both strings have been matched, then the snippet `exit !(sawWordA && sawWordB)` will return 0. If awk returns 0, then the ack command runs.

The ack `--nofilter` option tells ack to avoid reading from STDIN. Otherwise, ack would try to use the STDIN that the `read` command is using.

In the comments, Konrad asked how to use the above code when passing in variables in a shell script. Below is an example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo Usage: $0 {string1} {string2}
    E_BADARGS=65
    exit $E_BADARGS
fi

find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.r' | while read file; do
    awk "
        BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1; sawArg1 = 0; sawArg2 = 0 }
        /$1/ { sawArg1 = 1 }
        /$2/ { sawArg2 = 1 }
        sawArg1 && sawArg2 { exit } # stop reading lines if both matches seen
        END { exit !(sawArg1 && sawArg2) }
        " \
        "${file}" \
    && ack --nofilter -H -i "$1|$2" "${file}"
done
```

The above example doesn't escape any special characters in the arguments provided to the script. If escaping is needed, the script can be modified as needed.

Comment: How would I modify this script if I would like to call it in [tag:bash] and pass parameters to `wordA` and `wordB`. I reckon that I would have to do `"$1"` and `"$2"` but it should look for the syntax `wordA|wordB`?

Comment: @Konrad I've added example code for passing variables into a shell script.

Comment: Thanks very much, it's a really useful tool.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is pretty inefficient, but assuming you aren't searching a large directory, this should work.

```
find . -iname "*.r"  | while read file
do 
if (grep -qi "wordB" $file && grep -qi "wordA" $file)
  then
  echo "======== $file ======="
  grep --color=auto -iE "wordA|wordB" $file
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks very much for contributing the solution. I may be running it on a large directory, but any solution is better than no solution. I think I'll save it as a bash script as it will be handy. I'm wondering, would it be possible to make use of *--include* in *grep* instead of running the *find* at the beginning?